# Unable to launch spark using spark-shell

Tags: linux, apache-spark

I am trying to set up SPARK2 on my cloudera cluster. For that, I have JDK1.8:

[image]

I have installed scala 2.11.8 using the rpm file:

[image]

I have downloaded, extracted the spark version 2.2.0 on my home directory: /home/cloudera.

[image]

I made changes to the PATH variable in .bashrc as below:
[image]

But when I try to execute spark-shell from the home directory: /home/cloudera, it says no such file or directory which can be seen below:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-shell
/home/cloudera/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java: No such file or directory
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Could anyone let me know how can I fix the problem and configure it properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java/JVM applications (and spark-shell in particular) uses `java` binary to launch itself. Therefore they need to know where it is located, which is usually done via `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

In your case it's not reset explicitely and value from Clauder's default one Java distribution is used (even if it points to empty location).

You need to set `JAVA_HOME` pointing to correct java distribution directory for the user under which you want to launch `spark-shell` and other application.